# Rails - How can I display one nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

I have a new problem, I Create a web where I upload many images, using nested attributes and polymorphic table, in my index.html I want to show only one image, but I can't find how. But I'm new in rails.

photography.rb

```
class Photography < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :title, :description, presence: true
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :images, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:img_str].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

image.rb

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true

    mount_uploader :img_str, AssetUploader
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<% for photo in @photo %>
    <%= link_to photo.title, photography_path(photo) %>
    <% photo.images.each do |images| %>
        <%= images.img_str %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

With the for method I show all the image, try add .first, but says `undefined method first for 5:Fixnum.` I think that I have to create a helper method, but I not sure. Can anyone help me?. Thanks

Comment: `try add .first` - and where did you add it?

Comment: @BroiSatse in the sentence images.img_str.first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<% for photo in @photo %>
    <%= link_to photo.title, photography_path(photo) %>
    <%= photo.images.first.img_str if photo.images.any? %>
<% end %>
```

Also, `for` is very rarely used in ruby, instead do:

```
<% @photos.each do |photo| %>
```

Comment: I can't do that because, images is an array and I get undefined method `img_str' for nil:NilClass, when I try <%= photo.images.first.img_str %>

Comment: @SantDavalos - That means there are no images for a photo. Answer updated to handle this case as well. Also - images is not an array!

Comment: Sorry, the error is undefined method `img_str' for #<Image::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fe6d809aad0>

Comment: @SantDavalos - Are you sure you put first between images and img_str? `first` has no right to return CollectionProxy

Comment: Thank you very much man,I put First to the end, with this new line, works perfectly.